# Telethon client of Telegram stopped catching events

Tags: python, events, telegram, telethon

Until February 2, 2021, everything was OK. I received events from all telegram channels. After February 2, they only come from the channels of which I am the administrator, or from the chats of which I am a member. All other channels are completely ignored.

Can anyone tell you what could have happened?

P.S. I checked it through a spam bot, there are no account restrictions.
Here is the code. This is the classic way from the telethone guide.
'''

```
proxy = (proxy_ip, proxy_port, secret)
 
api_id = cfg.get_value('app', 'api_id', 'int')
api_hash = cfg.get_value('app', 'api_hash')
client = TelegramClient(app_name, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy,
                        connection=connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate)
 
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handler(event):
    #...
 
client.start()
print('STARTED')
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

'''

Comment: Are the channels very active, do they have a lot of members, do you have a lot of active sessions, are you using the client for something else other than listening for messages...? There's a lot of factors. Telegram can artificially slow it down.

Comment: The problem appeared shortly after Telegram entered replies in chats. I have a feeling that it is somehow connected.
And my client - I made it clean - only listens and outputs the channel ID and its name to the terminal.